# Can't print a browser.find_element_by_xpath with Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have code that looks like this:

```
print browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/ul/li/span[3]/span[3]').text
```

Gives an unexpected token on the browser.find_element_by_xpath part.

I don't understand what's going wrong.

Comment: You should make sure that your xpath query is actually returning an element and that it contains text.

Comment: Yeah it contains "€103". Is the error the symbol?

Comment: Please post the complete code you are executing and the error traceback you get.

Comment: I am not sure... but maybe you could assign the value to a string and convert it to UTF-8 format to check.

Comment: how did you get the xpath?

Comment: By using the inspect element tool in google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the value to utf format:

```
.encode("utf-8")
```

Stopped the error from happening.

Answer (score 0):

try surrounding your xpath with double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
print browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/ul/li/span[3]/span[3]").text
```